# UseEffect function to update a state variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-effect

I am new to react and I need to update the update the state variable in a function every time a function is rendered. This variable is used as a prop to a component.

The code is,

```
function Cal(props) {
     const [allEvents, setEvents] = useState({ events: [] });
     const [currentYear, setCurrentYear] =useState(moment().year().toString());
     useEffect(() => {
    getEvents();
 
  }, [currentYear]);
  async function getEvents() {
    const yearStart = `${currentYear}-01-01`;
    const yearEnd = `${currentYear}-12-31`;
    const data = await fetchEvents(yearStart, yearEnd, 'Discount', currentLang);
    console.log('data:', data);
    setEvents(data);
    console.log('allEvents:', allEvents);
  }
   return (
       <ChildComp
          eventData={allEvents}
        />
   );
}
```

UPDATE:
I need the function getEvents to be called every time the value of current year is changed.When I console log the value of data, I see the response data. But when I console log allEvents, I always see an empty array. I don't see the value of data updated.
?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: thanks @NicholasTower I need to fetch different set of events everytime the currentYear value changes. Hence I am calling the server in useeffect and I am passing the value allEvents to a child component that renders these events.If I don't have the value allEvents in a state the value doesnt get updated

Comment: @NicholasTowe updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Call the function outside of the useEffect.

```
function Cal(props) {
         const [allEvents, setEvents] = useState({ events: [] });

async function getEvents() {
      const yearStart = `${currentYear}-01-01`;
      const yearEnd = `${currentYear}-12-31`;
      const data = await fetchEvents(yearStart, yearEnd, 'Hard Discount', currentLang);
      console.log('data:', data);
      setEvents(data);
      console.log('allEvents:', allEvents);
    }


     useEffect(() => {
   
    getEvents();
  }, [allEvents]);
   return (
       <ChildComp
          eventData={allEvents}
        />
   );
}
```

For example ;

```
useEffect(() => {
    getCountries();
  }, []);

  const getCountries = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries");
    const data = await response.json();
    const arrayOfCountry = data.countries;

    setCountries(arrayOfCountry);
    setLoading(false);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you only need to fetch the async data once the component is rendered for the first time, so change the useEffect hook to a empty array and It will trigger the hook on the almost equivalent "componentDidMount()"

```
function Cal(props) {
     const [allEvents, setEvents] = useState({ events: [] });

     useEffect(() => {
    async function getEvents() {
      const yearStart = `${currentYear}-01-01`;
      const yearEnd = `${currentYear}-12-31`;
      const data = await fetchEvents(yearStart, yearEnd, 'Hard Discount', currentLang);
      console.log('data:', data);
      setEvents(data);
      console.log('allEvents:', allEvents);
    }
    getEvents();
  }, []);
   return (
       <ChildComp
          eventData={allEvents}
        />
   );
}
```

Comment: I need to get the events everytime the value of current year is updated

Comment: Great, now what changes the current year? This is the part that still does not make sense to me. The current year will only change in december 31 :D

Comment: There is a button that is used to move to prev and next year

Comment: Great, now It starts to make sense. If I were you debugging, my next step would be checking if the currentYear state has the expected input format in each scenario (coming from the (moment().year().toString()) and coming from your button. )

Comment: So the next step is to put something, like a alert, in the last line of  your getEvents function. Try to alert with some intuitive text, like alert(JSON.stringify(data)));
And check if the alert appears everytime that you change the date.

Comment: Looks like I figured out what's happening.. Since my state is updating based on the an await function, there seems to be a delay.. I should probably put that inside a promise based callback

Answer (score 0):

as per your code, useEffect has dependency [allEvents], that means every time allEvents changes getEvents() will be called,

I believe you just need it first time the component is mounted, so just remove dependency

```js
useEffect(() => {
   
    getEvents();
  }, [allEvents]);
```